# Can you use mov with an indirect operand as both source and destination?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, cpu-registers

Can I use `mov` with an indirect operand as both the source and destination?

E.g.

```
mov eax, OFFSET foo
mov esi, OFFSET bar
mov [eax],[esi + LENGTHOF bar]
```

From what I've tried I'm guessing you can't due to an `invalid instruction operand` error. But I haven't read anywhere that explicitly states you can't so I want to make sure it's not due to some other error.

Comment: It's possible in one _special case_ ... for `mov [esp],[...]` / `mov [...],[esp]` you could use `push` / `pop` with a `m32` memory operand. The disadvantage (beyond the implicit need to have the 2nd address operand in `esp`) is that `esp` changes as well.

Comment: Related, basically a duplicate: [Why isn't movl from memory to memory allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33794169) although that spends more time on the "why not" part.  Also [Why cannot do mov \[eax\], \[ebx\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54482505) and other older/newer duplicates have various versions of the same explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The x86 `mov` instruction does not support memory-to-memory moves.

Have a look at [Volume 2: Instruction Set Reference](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html), namely the `MOV` instruction.  There are `reg <- reg`, `mem <- reg`, and `reg <- mem` forms, but no `mem <- mem`.

To move data from memory to memory, one must either use an intermediate register, or the `movs` instruction, which moves a value from address `DS:ESI` to `ES:EDI`. This is the reason those registers are named as such (source index, and destination index).

Comment: Ah, alright. Did not occur to me that this indirect addressing is also memory-to-memory. Thanks! Will accept soon.

Comment: Nit-picking: Unless you count `movs` and `pop`s to memory locations.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thank you. I've re-worded my opening sentence.