# too many references for 'mov' when using two 64-bit registers?

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86-64, gnu-assembler, intel-syntax

I'm trying to compile one very simple program, but I get 2 errors that I can not fix:

```
1.s:13:Error: too many memory references for 'mov'
1.s:15:Error: too many memory references for 'lea'
```

Here is my code, I hope someone sees my mistake.

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.data
message: .asciz "Hello World\n"
.text
.global main
main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    lea rdi, message
    call printf
    mov rax, 0
    pop rbp
    ret
```

Comment: `rpb` is a typo for `rbp`, but that should just assemble as a store to that symbol name.  Are you sure you're assembling in 64-bit mode?  In 32-bit mode, `rdi` and `rsp` are just symbol names, not registers.  `gcc -c foo.s` doesn't give any errors on my x86-64 GNU/Linux desktop.

Comment: (The code won't of course link because of that typo, and `lea` is pointless if you're not going to use RIP-relative addressing like `lea rdi, [RIP + message]`, though.  And your code is in the .data section, not .text.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I corrected that typo and added .text section, but it is the same

Comment: Yeah, like I said, the typo doesn't explain the error message.  Likely you're assembling in 32-bit mode, like `gcc -m32`, which would only be the default on a 32-bit system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code assembles + links just fine for me, on my x86-64 Arch GNU/Linux system:
`gcc -no-pie foo.S`

**Those error messages match what I get with `gcc -c -m32 foo.S`, so probably you're using a 32-bit system where `-m32` is the default for your GCC.**  If `gcc -m64 -no-pie` works, you can assemble + link it, otherwise you'll have to upgrade your system to 64-bit.

**In 32-bit mode, RBP and so on aren't register names**, so GAS just treats them as unknown symbol names.  And of course [x86 doesn't allow instructions with two explicit memory operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33794169/why-isnt-movl-from-memory-to-memory-allowed) like `mov mem2, mem1`.  (And `lea` needs a register destination, and `mov rax, 0` also errors on the ambiguous operand-size for the store.)

(I had to use `-no-pie` because you wrote `lea rdi, message` instead of `lea rdi, [rip+message]` to use RIP-relative addressing [instead of 32-bit absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux): [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register))